# Tidying data in Julia using @linq from the DataFramesMeta package

Tags: dataframe, linq, julia, dataframesmeta.jl

I would like to tidy my data using the `@linq` macro from the `DataFramesMeta` package.

The result should give the same result as the code below:

```
using CSV, DataFrames, Dates

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"
download(url, joinpath(pwd(), "confirmed.csv"))

df = CSV.read(joinpath(pwd(), "confirmed.csv"))
rename!(df, 1 => :Province, 2 => :Country)
select!(df, Not([:Province, :Lat, :Long]))
df = combine(groupby(df, :Country), names(df)[2:end] .=> sum .=> names(df)[2:end])
df = stack(df, Not(:Country), :Country, variable_name=:Date, value_name=:Confirmed)
df[:Date] = parse.(Dates.Date, String.(df[:Date]), Dates.DateFormat("m/d/Y")) .+ Dates.Year(2000)

println(last(df, 10))
```

Result:

```
10×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Country            │ Date       │ Confirmed │
│     │ String             │ Date       │ Int64     │
├─────┼────────────────────┼────────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ United Kingdom     │ 2020-10-29 │ 968456    │
│ 2   │ Uruguay            │ 2020-10-29 │ 3044      │
│ 3   │ Uzbekistan         │ 2020-10-29 │ 66392     │
│ 4   │ Venezuela          │ 2020-10-29 │ 91280     │
│ 5   │ Vietnam            │ 2020-10-29 │ 1177      │
│ 6   │ West Bank and Gaza │ 2020-10-29 │ 52571     │
│ 7   │ Western Sahara     │ 2020-10-29 │ 10        │
│ 8   │ Yemen              │ 2020-10-29 │ 2062      │
│ 9   │ Zambia             │ 2020-10-29 │ 16325     │
│ 10  │ Zimbabwe           │ 2020-10-29 │ 8349      │
```

My code so far using `@linq` is:

```
using DataFramesMeta

df = @linq CSV.read(joinpath(pwd(), "data", "time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")) |>
    rename(1 => :Province, 2 => :Country) |>
    select(vcat(names(df)[2], names(df)[5:end]))
```

However, I'm stuck at the point of grouping and summarizing the data.
Any suggestions how to complete this `linq` query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataFramesMeta.jl is undergoing a significant refactoring now. Maybe @pdeffebach can suggest an idiomatic use of it using the functionality on master.

Here is how I would rewrite your code using raw DataFrames.jl and Pipe.jl:

```
df = CSV.read(joinpath(pwd(), "confirmed.csv"), DataFrame)

@pipe df |>
      rename(_, 1 => :Province, 2 => :Country) |> # avoid ! to make sure we do not mutate the source
      select!(_, Not([:Province, :Lat, :Long])) |>
      groupby(_, :Country) |>
      combine(_, valuecols(_) .=> sum .=> valuecols(_)) |>
      stack(_, Not(:Country), :Country, variable_name=:Date, value_name=:Confirmed) |>
      transform!(_, :Date => ByRow(x -> parse(Date, string(x), DateFormat("m/d/Y")) + Year(2000)) => :Date) |>
      last(_, 10)
```

Note that in your code:

- `CSV.read(joinpath(pwd(), "confirmed.csv"))` (add `DataFrame` as a second argument as in my code)
- `df[:Date]` should be `df.Date` or `df."Date"` (the second style is in case the name containse e.g. spaces)

are deprecated.

Comment: Just to add on to this, DataFramesMeta does not yet make it easy to work with collections of columns defined programmatically, i.e. via `Not` or `valuecols`. For this kind of operation, it's best to stick with vanilla DataFrames and not use `@linq`. @pipe` is good enough here. If you dislike using the `_` you can also try Hose.jl, which allows you to optionally omit the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the correct code for the depreciated items?

Comment: I suppose the select! and transform! should be without bang, right?

Comment: `select!` and `transform!` should be with `!` as they are in the processing pipeline so it is better to do in-place operation as it is faster. I commented in the poper code in the anwer.